# React input setState for array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

Look at the form to edit phone numbers in [Google Contacts](https://contacts.google.com/).

[image]

Let's say my state looks like:

```
    this.state = {
        phones: [
            {
                country: 'US',
                label: 'Home',
                number: '555'
            }
        ],

    };
```

My HTML would look like, in a loop and simplified to be all text inputs:

```
<input type="text" value={this.state.phones[index].country} onChange={this.handleChange} />
<input type="text" value={this.state.phones[index].number} onChange={this.handleChange} />
<input type="text" value={this.state.phones[index].label} onChange={this.handleChange} />
```

How would you implement the `handleChange` to call `setState` while supporting the fact that it is an array, and that each item in the array has multiple properties?

I saw pieces of answers in other questions, but nothing complete.

Comment: If I follow your question correctly you should create a component `Phone` which handles it's own state

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like the following and also make a `Phone` component.

```js
class Phone extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <p>{this.props.label}</p>
        <input
          type="number"
          onChange={this.props.updateNumber}
          value={this.props.number}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    phones: [
      {
        name: "US",
        number: ""
      },
      {
        name: "UK",
        number: ""
      }
    ]
  };

  updateNumber = (e, index) => {
    const phones = this.state.phones;
    phones[index].number = e.target.value;
    this.setState({
      phones
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {this.state.phones.map((phone, i) => {
          return (
            <Phone
              updateNumber={e => {
                this.updateNumber(e, i);
              }}
              number={this.state.phones[i].number}
              label={phone.name}
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'></div>
```

Comment: Interesting. Is that considered best-practice? 
Also, (sorry newbie here), but will the state be propagated upwards? At the end of the day, the actual form is in the parent component, and it will be the one sending the updated user profile to the server, etc.

Comment: I believe it is considered the correct way of doing this. It was something that used to catch me out before. I know what you mean by sending the data to the server from the parent component. You could pass the data back to the parent from the child component

Comment: So you are saying, the sub-component will call a function on its parent (which it received as an input). I think we're back to partial answers here, because in our case we have an array of sub-components. So how would the sub-component update the correct item in the array?

Comment: you know what, I am looking here as I know what you mean exactly now - I think I am a little confused too - gonna try and crack it. AIt is a strange one when you try and set the state in the parent - that is where it gets caught

Comment: @NathanH I think the updated answer is what you are looking for

Comment: I think we’re getting there ;) Except in your example, only the number is editable. While in reality all fields are editable. Just like the Google Contacts example.

Comment: if all fields are editable it is the same thing really. You could just create a different method to handle each input or else do something like this - https://medium.com/@tmkelly28/handling-multiple-form-inputs-in-react-c5eb83755d15

Comment: I’m thinking, onChange, call the parent function but passing the entire state of the subcomponent. So it would replace the entire line...

Answer (score 0):

2 options

1. Make a Phone component with it's own state as suggested by Paul Fitzgerald.
2. Add the index to a `data-index` attribute and check for the value in `handleChange`.

Example of 2:

```
<input type="text" value={this.state.phones[index].country} data-index="0" onChange={this.handleChange} />
<input type="text" value={this.state.phones[index].number} data-index="0" onChange={this.handleChange} />
<input type="text" value={this.state.phones[index].label} data-index="0" onChange={this.handleChange} />
```

then in `handleChange`:

```
handleChange(e) {
    ...
    const i = e.target.dataset.index;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Regarding option (2), how does this help me? Getting the index wasn't really the problem, I meant, how do I then update this information in `setState`?

Comment: Oh right, there are few ways to update a single object in a state array, but that's a different question. Paul's answer is really the better way to go.