# How can I pass in an unknown amount of objects in a dynamic react form to my sql database?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, database, backend

I'm having trouble connecting 0-6 dynamically rendered form elements to the backend/database using react. Perhaps the way I'm attempting to do this is not supported? Any advice would be really appreciated.

ERD of Database:
[image]

Index.js file in "backend" directory:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const mysql = require('mysql');
//const { restart } = require('nodemon');

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.json());

app.listen('3001', () => {
    console.log("Running on port 3001.");
});

const db = mysql.createPool ({
    host: '[redacted]',
    user: '[redacted]',
    password: '[redacted]',
    database: '[redacted]'
});

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send("backend");
});

app.post('/', function (req, res) {
    db.getConnection(function (err, db) {
        const lastName = req.body.lastName;
        const firstName = req.body.firstName;
        const address = req.body.address;
        const street = req.body.street;
        const apartment = req.body.apartment;
        const city = req.body.city;
        const zipcode = req.body.zipcode;
        const phone = req.body.phone;
        const dateOfArrival = req.body.dateOfArrival;
        const dateReceived = req.body.dateReceived;
        const countryOfOrigin = req.body.countryOfOrigin;
        const immigrationStatus = req.body.immigrationStatus;
        const speaksEnglish = req.body.speaksEnglish;
        const notes = req.body.notes;

        const childField = req.body.childField; //and array of information about the children

        const sqlInsertParent = "INSERT INTO Parent (parent_id, lastName, firstName, address, street, apartment, city, zipcode, " 
                            + "phone, dateOfArrival, dateReceived, countryOfOrigin, immigrationStatus, speaksEnglish, notes) VALUES "
                            + "(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

        const sqlInsertChild = "INSERT INTO Children (child_id, parent_id, childFirstName, gender, age, shoe, childNotes) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

        //insert the parent into the database
        db.query(sqlInsertParent, ["", lastName, firstName, address, street, apartment, 
                                    city, zipcode, phone, dateOfArrival, dateReceived, 
                                    countryOfOrigin, immigrationStatus, speaksEnglish, notes], (err, result) => {
                                        console.log(err);
        });
        
        //Get the max parent_id from the Parent table (this will go into the Children table)
        db.query('SELECT max(parent_id) FROM Parent', function (error, results, fields) {
            /*NOTE: The Parent table will never be null because even if it's empty at first, the insert
            into the parent table comes before the insert into the child table.*/
            if (error) {
                throw error;
            }
            //Convert the result into a number: 
            var s = JSON.stringify(results);
            var json = JSON.parse(s);
            var obj = json[0];
            objVal = Object.values(obj);
            var maxParentID = Number(objVal);

            //Insert the children into the database
            //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51193704/react-input-setstate-for-array-of-objects
            // for(let i = 0; i < childField.length; i++) {
            //     db.query(sqlInsertChild, ["", maxParentID,childField[i].childFirstName, childField[i].gender, childField[i].age, 
            //                                 childField[i].shoe, childField[i].childNotes], (err, result) => {
            //                                 console.log(err);
            //     });
            // }
        });
    });
});
```

help.js in "frontend" directory -- this is where the form is:

```
import Sponsors from "./Sponsors";
import ChildForm from "./ChildForm";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from 'axios'; //allows us to create api requests

// this component renders the request help page

const Help = () => {

    const [sample, sampleSet] = useState(null);

    console.log(sample);

    const addChild = (e) => {
        var children = []

        switch (e.target.value) {
            case '0' : setChildrenState(null);
            case '1' :
                setChildrenState(
                    <ChildForm childTitle={'Child 1'} sampleSet={sampleSet}/>
                )
                break;
            case '2' :
                setChildrenState(
                    <>
                        <ChildForm childTitle={'Child 1'}/>
                        <ChildForm childTitle={'Child 2'}/>
                    </>
                )
                break;
            case '3' :
                setChildrenState(
                    <>
                        <ChildForm childTitle={'Child 1'}/>
                        <ChildForm childTitle={'Child 2'}/>
                        <ChildForm childTitle={'Child 3'}/>
                    </>
                )
                break;
            case '4' :
                setChildrenState(
                    <>
                        <ChildForm childTitle={'Child 1'}/>
                        <ChildForm childTitle={'Child 2'}/>
                        <ChildForm childTitle={'Child 3'}/>
                        <ChildForm childTitle={'Child 4'}/>
                    </>
                )
                break;
            case '5' :
                setChildrenState(
                    <>
                        <ChildForm childTitle={'Child 1'}/>
                        <ChildForm childTitle={'Child 2'}/>
                        <ChildForm childTitle={'Child 3'}/>
                        <ChildForm childTitle={'Child 4'}/>
                        <ChildForm childTitle={'Child 5'}/>
                    </>
                )
                break;
            case '6' :
                setChildrenState(
                    <>
                        <ChildForm childTitle={'Child 1'}/>
                        <ChildForm childTitle={'Child 2'}/>
                        <ChildForm childTitle={'Child 3'}/>
                        <ChildForm childTitle={'Child 4'}/>
                        <ChildForm childTitle={'Child 5'}/>
                        <ChildForm childTitle={'Child 6'}/>
                    </>
                )
                break;
            default: 
                //no default because the user can only select 1-> 6
        }
    }

    const [lastName, setLastName] = useState('');
    const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('');
    const [address, setAddress] = useState('');
    const [street, setStreet] = useState('');
    const [apartment, setApartment] = useState('');
    const [city, setCity] = useState('');
    const [zipcode, setZipcode] = useState('');
    const [phone, setPhone] = useState('');
    const [dateOfArrival, setDateOfArrival] = useState(null);
    const [dateReceived, setDateReceived] = useState(null);
    const [countryOfOrigin, setCountryOfOrigin] = useState('');
    const [immigrationStatus, setImmigrationStatus] = useState(null);
    const [speaksEnglish, setSpeaksEnglish] = useState(null);
    const [notes, setNotes] = useState('');

    //const [childField, setChildrenState] = useState(null);
    
    const submitHelpForm = () => {
        console.log(childField);
        axios.post('http://localhost:3001/', {lastName: lastName, firstName: firstName, address: address, 
                                                street: street, apartment: apartment, city: city, 
                                                zipcode: zipcode, phone: phone, dateOfArrival: dateOfArrival, 
                                                dateReceived: dateReceived, countryOfOrigin: countryOfOrigin, 
                                                immigrationStatus: immigrationStatus, speaksEnglish: speaksEnglish, notes: notes,
                                                /*childField: childField*/
                                                }).then(() => {
                                                    alert('successful insert');
                                                });
    };

    return (
        <div className="help-request-container">
            <h3 className="request-header">
                If you are a newcomer and your children need basic necessities, please complete the form below.
                We will contact you soon with more information about becoming a Starting Point family.
            </h3>

            <form className="request-help-form" /*onSubmit={submitHelpForm} */>
                <input type={'text'} placeholder='Parent Last Name' maxlength='250' required onChange={(e) => {setLastName(e.target.value)}}/>
                <input type={'text'} placeholder='Parent First Name' maxlength='250' required onChange={(e) => {setFirstName(e.target.value)}}/>
                <input type={'text'} placeholder='Street Number - example: 2311' maxlength='10' required onChange={(e) => {setAddress(e.target.value)}}/>
                <input type={'text'} placeholder='Street Name - example: Hamlet Way' maxlength='250' required onChange={(e) => {setStreet(e.target.value)}}/>
                <input type={'text'} placeholder='Apt/Suite/Unit/Building/Floor - example: Apt. 4' maxlength='20' onChange={(e) => {setApartment(e.target.value)}}/>
                <input type={'text'} placeholder='City - example: Manhattan' maxlength='25' required onChange={(e) => {setCity(e.target.value)}}/>
                <input type={'text'} placeholder='Postal Code - example: 80456' maxlength='15' required onChange={(e) => {setZipcode(e.target.value)}}/>
                <input type={'text'} placeholder="Phone Number" required onChange={(e) => {setPhone(e.target.value)}}/>
                <label for="date">Input Date arrived in US:</label>
                    <input type={'date'} placeholder='Date arrived in US' required onChange={(e) => {setDateOfArrival(e.target.value)}}/>
                <label for="date">Input Current Date:</label>
                    <input type={'date'} placeholder='Current Date' required onChange={(e) => {setDateReceived(e.target.value)}}/>
                <input type={'text'} placeholder='Country of Origin - example: Afghanistan' maxlength='250' required onChange={(e) => {setCountryOfOrigin(e.target.value)}}/>
                <label for="Immigration Status">Select an Immigration Status:</label>
                    <select id="immigration status" name="immigrationStatus" onChange={(e) => {setImmigrationStatus(e.target.value)}}>
                        <option value="Other">Other</option>
                        <option value="SIV">SIV</option>
                        <option value="Evacuee">Evacuee</option>
                        <option value="Parolee">Parolee</option>
                        <option value="Asylee">Asylee</option>
                        <option value="Diversity Visa Holder">Diversity Visa Holder</option>
                    </select>
                <label for="language">Do you speak English?</label>
                    <select id="language" name="language" onChange={(e) => {setSpeaksEnglish(e.target.value)}}>
                        <option value="No">No</option>
                        <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                   </select>
                <input type={"text"} placeholder='Notes About Parent' maxlength='250' onChange={(e) => {setNotes(e.target.value)}}/>

                <label for="children">How many children do you have?</label>
                    <select id="children" name="children" onChange={addChild}>
                        <option value={0}>No Response</option>
                        <option value={1}>1</option>
                        <option value={2}>2</option>
                        <option value={3}>3</option>
                        <option value={4}>4</option>
                        <option value={5}>5</option>
                        <option value={6}>6</option>
                    </select>
                <div className="child-add-form">
                    {childField}
                </div>

                <input type="submit" value="Submit" onClick={submitHelpForm}></input>
            </form>
            {/*{ console.log(child) }*/}
            
            {/* render sponsors component at bottom of page. */}
            <Sponsors />
        </div>
    )
}

export default Help
```

Comment: your ERD does not correspond to your code. please update either correct ERD or correct code

Comment: @gear4 Apologies! The correct ERD has been added. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

Your request to the server has to have the children in an array. Your coding style seems to bring forth a beginner level, so I would suggest adding one state item per child (6 total) and constructing an array based on how many children have been added.

This can be done relatively easily with a couple of changes: use a state item to hold the selected amount, and use props to update individual children states